# How to stop Finder deleting "Favorites" bar shortcuts that don't open instantly

Tags: macos, finder

I work in folders on a shared drive on a mostly-Windows office network. I keep these in the "favourites" bar in Finder for easy access. Most of my working days start like this:

- I open Finder, and click on the shortcut for the folder I need
- Two things happen simultaneously:

  - My Mac connects with the drive then opens the folder. So far, so good.
  - Finder sees that there was a moment's delay before the folder opened, while the network connection completed, **and automatically deletes the shortcut**
- So I then need to go to the containing folder, and re-create the shortcut

Is there any way to stop Finder doing this?

I'm aware of workarounds like using a shortcut on my desktop, or manually connecting to the drive first, etc etc. I'm looking for a solution where I don't need to remember to stop myself doing something natural and intuitive like clicking on a favourites shortcut every morning.

Thinking about it, I'd also quite like to stop it auto-deleting *any* favourites links, even if they never work and are genuinely broken links: if a folder link breaks, I'll want to be able to look at the old file path to help me work out where a colleague might have moved it to. So solutions that turns off all auto-deletion of shortcuts is also welcome.

---

To add a little more info, once connected the shared drive appears in the "Shared" section of the Finder sidebar. "Get info" on it gives its "Kind" as "PC", and no further info.

It looks like Finder is set up such that if you click on a favourite, and Finder doesn't get back either "success" or some sort of specific known "connecting" message of a type that network Macs send to other Macs, it immediately deletes the shortcut. I'd like to have it not auto-delete shortcuts.

Comment: Granted I am not on a Windows network here, but I cannot reproduce this. Disconnecting completely from the source of the shared folder (another Mac on my local network) then clicking on the shared folder's icon in Favorites results in a short delay while it establishes a connection, but it doesn't remove the favorite. What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: I've seen the problem on Mavericks and Mountain Lion. I expect it's related to it not being a Mac-to-Mac network connection, I imagine there's some Mac-specific "Connecting..." message when it's Mac-to-Mac. Whatever the cause, I'd like to turn the auto-delete off.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a somewhat prevalent issue, without a clear fix yet. Here's a link to one of the Apple Support threads that I think is a similar problem: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5556541?start=45&tstart=0

Comment: Thanks! Wow, five pages of people having the exact same problem... there's one nice workaround there I might try ("...create an alias. After you create the alias drag it to your sidebar.  They seem to stay in place from what I've found. You can delete the alias from the server once you move it to the sidebar") but as you say, no clear fix